# Is there a fast way to lock my SVN repository's trunk?

Tags: svn, version-control

There are moments when I need to be sure that no one is committing to either a specific branch or to my trunk.  Release builds and reintegration merges are an example.

SVN "locking" all the files is not realistic (very long since project is huge).  I also don't believe that locking prevents someone from committing new files.

What would be a quick way to make sure no one commits anything to the folder until I'm done what I'm doing?

Thanks

Comment: Could you not create a new branch for the release build. And do all your building etc on this new branch which no one else is working on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We faced this problem when compiling our projects for release builds, where a build server property (CruiseControl.NET project label) is used as part of the assembly and installer version.

The solution is easy where you are branching (or tagging) the working copy, e.g. for release builds.

Workflow:

1. Checkout fresh working copy of trunk (or branch).
2. Build your release, this updates files leaving your working copy in a modified state.
3. If your build succeeds, svn copy the *working copy* into your new branch or tag.

If you want to commit your working copy without branching, then as you say this will fail (or at the least be unreliable) if someone has modified that path of the repository.

A way to solve this would be to use [svn authorization control](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth), adding a build server user to svn and have different `authz` files for the repository.

Workflow:

1. Replace `authz` with file granting write access for build server user and read access for all other users.
2. Perform your build as per normal.
3. Replace `authz` with file granting normal access for all users.

Note that svn authorization allows path-based control, so you could restrict this just to trunk (or wherever) to reduce impact on users.

Another way using a similar approach (same workflow) would be replacing [pre-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html) and checking the user; rejecting the commit (with appropriate error message) if it wasn't your build server user performing the commit.  Again, this could be path based (with a little extra regex work) if needed.

Answer (score 8):

If you're making a release build, the first thing you do is check out a particular revision.

It doesn't really matter if someone commits something else during that time - it won't affect your build.

Comment: It somewhat does.  My build number contains the svn version.  Running my automatic build generates a bunch of files which need to be committed.  The last step of my build is therefore to check-in.  I've tried just adding 1 to the revision number but sometimes I run into problems during my build and by the time I've fixed them someone has committed something to that folder.

Comment: You would be better of changing your process so that it doesn't require checking in generated files.

Files that you generate automatically don't belong into source control.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  It's a system I've inherited.  We have plans to change it but for now, I'd just like a quick way to lock the trunk.

Comment: @oefe, I disagree. There are advantages to adding generated files to a repository (such as MSI or EXE installers).  Can you guarantee that X years from now your build server will be able to compile the same version of your source code as it was originally compiled (and released).  It is far *far* easier to have the source code and the MSI/EXE generated by the source code in the same place. Obviously this is in a branch or tag and not trunk.

Comment: the problem with auto-generated files is that every time you build the program, these files become out of date in the repository, which very quickly becomes multi-user hell

Comment: @Si it should be able to, any machine checking out the source should be able to compile it exactly the same.  If it's not then whatever dependencies need to be added to source control.

Comment: Why not just tag a copy rather than relying on the the build revision number? The copy is of a specific revision, and thus "atomic", and then you can check your generated artifacts back in to the tagged branch, without any regard to the actual revision. (You could name the tag "BUILD-REV-1234" if you like, to tell what version you cut it from).

Comment: @Davy8 I agree, in theory.  However, software is always getting upgraded, new compiler versions, new runtimes (.NET, Java VMs) new 3rd party libraries, etc.  Unless you maintain the same version for all of  these, how can you guarantee that you will have the same MSI/EXE as first released? (even though your source code is still the same)

Comment: You could consider having everything necessary to build your code in the repository. Yes, even your compiler binaries if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. It sounds as though your development work-flow could do with some changes, since you're encountering this issue. In particular, on such a large project, you should consider a work-flow that is more controlled, so development changes aren't coming in at the same time, and on the same branch, as a release build that is in progress. You mentioned reintegration merges for example—surely you can coordinate the project so that reintegration merges aren't happening at the same time as a release build. And developers shouldn't be directly committing to the branch that a release build is being done on.

Possibilities:

- Communicate effectively with the developers.

  - Announce what you're about to do.
  - Developers should at least know that they shouldn't commit to a branch on which a release build is in-progress.
- Do builds in a branch. Then tag the branch when the build is complete.
- Developers do development work on separate branches. Then integration merges are done into an integration branch (maybe `trunk`).

  - Developers should know that an integration shouldn't be done on a branch on which a release build is in-progress.

Answer (score 1):

We'll first, you might try performing those operations on specific revisions rather than the head.

If the revision isn't an option, I'd next suggest that you tag the revision you want to build or whatever and operate on that one. This obviously won't work for merges as it defeats the purpose.

But, to get to the crux of your question, the quickest way I can think of is to prevent incoming information is to halt the server itself. I am not an SVN expert however, I've admin'd a box for several years.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much access you have to the server, send an announcement telling no one to commit until some time.

If you can't do that, then checkout/checkin using the `file://` or `file+ssh://` for release builds and during that time shutdown the SVN server process. (be it apache, or svnserver) then restart it as soon as the build is done.

Also, be sure to rework this so it doesn't require locking the repo as soon as possible. (I realize this is just a temporary thing that you inherited)

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is in my humble opinion.

1. Lock the trunk
2. create a tag
3. release the Lock on the trunk
4. export the tag
5. build the code
6. if build is successful lock the tagged version (otherwise delete it)

This is how I do it and I have a script for the tagging part

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#    Copyleft
#

#
# Use with caution
#
#
#
# This script expects 2 variables in the environment to be set : USERNAME & PASSWORD
# These are needed to access our Subversion server.
#

#
# This script tags the code of each project @ HEAD
# Later version will be more sofisticated to allow tagging at a specified REVISION (it should already be the case but ... )
#
# This script must be saved un iso-8858-1 with UNIX LF
# ##############################################################################################################################################

# for debugging
set -x
set -v


# The Current verion of the tagging script is


BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)
export BASE_SVN_URL=https://my-svn-server/svn/repository/
export ROOT_DIR=../..
export VERSION="v0000.01"
export REVISION=HEAD
export TAG_NAME=TC_05

for PRJ in MODULE_1 MODULE_2 MODULE_3
do
  svn lock --username ${USERNAME} --password ${PASSWORD}  --no-auth-cache --non-interactive  --trust-server-cert   --force                     \
                                            ${BASE_SVN_URL)${PRJ}/trunk/                                                                       \
                                            -m "Locking the trunk of ${PRJ} before generating a Tagged version : ${VERSION} Tag is : ${TAG_NAME}"
done


for PRJ in MODULE_1 MODULE_2 MODULE_3
do
  svn copy --username ${USERNAME} --password ${PASSWORD}  --no-auth-cache --non-interactive  --trust-server-cert                               \
                                           ${BASE_SVN_URL)${PRJ}/trunk@${REVISION}                                                             \
                                           ${BASE_SVN_URL)${PRJ}/tags/${VERSION}/${TAG_NAME}                                                   \
                                           -m "$1"

  svn lock --username ${USERNAME} --password ${PASSWORD}  --no-auth-cache --non-interactive  --trust-server-cert                               \
                                            ${BASE_SVN_URL)${PRJ}/tags/${VERSION}/${TAG_NAME}                                                  \
                                            -m "Tagged version cannot be modified afterwards"


  svn unlock --username ${USERNAME} --password ${PASSWORD}  --no-auth-cache --non-interactive  --trust-server-cert   --force                   \
                                            ${BASE_SVN_URL)${PRJ}/trunk/                                                                       \
                                            -m "Locking before generating a Tagged version"
done

set +x
set +v

#
# TODO :
# 
# 1. Ensure that the following parameters are set correctly
#      _ username / password (though not mandatory)
#      _ Commit message, VERSION & TAG ought to be set before start
#      _ ... ?
# 2. Ensure that the directory structure exist
# 3. Ensure that the required variable are set before starting ... but anyway the script will fail :)
# 4. Check the return code of the important commands command.
# 5.
```

The build of my code is located in another script.
Long scripts are cool but tend to raise issue when failing early in the process, leaving systems in an unknown state.
The script provided has not yet been fully tested nor has been extensively used on our system to guarantee they are error free.

**BUT** I would recommend to seldom use svn locking.

At the very end before the release it is a mean to ensure no last minute mistake is not putting your release at jeopardy ... but good communication should allow you to use almost the same code but specifying a commit number

\T,

Answer (score 0):

The passwd file could be changed temporarily while work is being done.  The downside is that this affects the entire repository, not just one folder.

Comment: @Mr Grieves it's not. I wouldn't call this a 'brilliant' suggestion either, but it can be enough in certain situations, so it's a valid answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Need I push my [pre-commit](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) hook again?

This can handle a lot of things, but preventing people from modifying files is the main thrust of it. You can control commit behavior via a control file:

```
[ FILE The repository is now locked and you are no longer allowed to change files]
Match = .*
access = read-only
users = @ALL

[ File Except for me. I can do whatever I want]
match = .*
access = read-write
users = si
```

The control file can live inside the repository, so you don't need server access. Just checkout the control file, edit it and commit. (And, of course, the pre-commit script controls the access to who can modify the control file!)

What you probably want to do is to use branches for releases. We use Jenkins and do everything via the Jenkins build number. Developers will say "I want to branch build #50, and that gets branched, or "Let's tag build #51, and that gets tagged.

We branch when you probably want to lock your repository. However, we let developers continue on the trunk, and then limit who can operate on a branch:

```
[group cm]
users = si

[group Release]
users = bob, alice

[group developers]
users = robert fred cindy @Release

[file You do not have access to make changes to this repository]
match = .*
access = read-only
users = @all

[file Let all developers work on the trunk]
file = /trunk/**
access = read-write
users = @developers

[file only release group can work on the 4.5 branch]
file = /branches/4.5/**
access = read-write
users = @release

[file You cannot edit a tag. You can only create a tag]
file = /tags/*/
access = add-only
Users = all

[file CM group can do anything]
file = .*
access = read-write
users = @CM
```

Permissions are read downward and the last permission that applies to you is the one you get. Developers can access trunk. The release people can work on the 4.5 branch, but not on any other branches. The special `add-only` access allows you to create a tag, but not modify the tag. The `/tags/*/` means that you can only create tags directly under the tag directory, and it must be a directory that was copied from another location.

Answer (score 0):

The pretty old question. My answer may help someone who uses the Tortoise SVN

1. Right-click the project folder in  your local system, select TortoiseSVN->Properties
2. Click New->NeedsLock
3. Choose Locking required in the dialog:
4. Click OK
5. Commit the file
6. Done!

[image]