# Is there way to block any change in SVN?

Tags: svn, administration

We want check versions than we want to freeze project (block any change at SVN). Is there any way? I don't want create branche. I just want freeze project on a few hours.

The best way is say something as:
If you don't have login as (array of allowLoginsUser) then "you havent commit!" and block
else "allow commit" and commit

Is there any way?

Comment: Why don't you branch? This is the default working model thesedays.

Comment: Because this isn't milestone. One team of developer want to entry large change into our main libraries. He prepared extreme large units test which cover around 95% code. And we must freeze this project on tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the `svn lock` command.

You can find more information about it in the [SVN book's 'Locking' chapter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.locking.html).

Typically, you will do something like

```
svn lock -m "Freeze project for a few hours" PATH
# do what you need to do
svn unlock PATH
```

where `PATH` is your repository.

Comment: you can only lock files, not folders. So you need to write asvn lock command for each file.

Comment: You're right that locking should be applied on a per-file basis. Your idea about using several `authz` files is actually simplier (and is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2225859/1374267)).

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

1. use the authz path based authorization and disable write access for all users
2. use a pre-commit hook to disable **all** write access to a specific repository by placing an

   exit 1;

   into it
3. use a more sophisticated pre-commit hook, examinig the changed files and denying access if the freezed project occurs

They are ranked by difficulty and effort starting on easiest.

Comment: 1.5. Use Access Control Groups in your path based authorization to allow _(array of allowLoginsUser)_ to commit. [link](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could just temporarily edit the ./conf/passwd file (if you're using password user authentication) and comment out all of the users "#" in front of their username. Save the file and restart the SVN server.

Then uncomment their names out afterwards.